# how to test InAppPurchases in android if we have not licence key of play store?

Tags: android

hello can anyone solve my problem today is my third day the same issue i am facing can anyone help me please?
i want to implement payment method (in-App-Purchases) in my android app for testing purpose but i have not play store account so that i can take public licence key from there  i see many tutorials in which licences key is necessary  so how can i do this job done ?
is there any way so that we can test this payment method without google play store account ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Eventually you will need a developer account, and it's a one time payment.
You will need this in order to test your purchases, as you need to create test accounts under your developer account.

[This will give you more information](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/test-iab-app.html)

Answer (score 0):

for testing you can use PRODUCT_ID="android.test.purchased"

> ```
> BillingProcessor bp = new BillingProcessor(this, "", new BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
>
>                     }
>
>                     @Override
>                     public void onBillingError(int errorCode, Throwable error) {
>                         Log.e("purchse", "onBillingError: " + Integer.toString(errorCode));
>                     }
>
>                     @Override
>                     public void onBillingInitialized() {
>                         Log.e("purchse", "onBillingInitialized");
>                         readyToPurchase = true;
>
>                     }
>
>                     @Override
>                     public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
>                         Log.e("purchse", "onPurchaseHistoryRestored");
>                         for (String sku : bp.listOwnedProducts()) {
>                             Log.d("purchse", "Owned Managed Product: " + sku);
>                                                }
>                         for (String sku : bp.listOwnedSubscriptions())
>                             Log.d("purchse", "Owned Subscription: " + sku);
>                     }
>                 });
> ```

---

bp.purchase(this, PRODUCT_ID);